# Does spring-data-dynamodb support Local Secondary Index?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm using the [spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb) in my project.
I know that's possible to use Global Secondary Index (GSI), there's an example in the documentation.

But, I need to use **Local Secondary Indexes (LSI)**, I couldn't find any example of it.

Do you know if spring-data-dynamodb supports LSI?

Thank you!

*ps: I'm not asking about the difference between them, or when to use one or another approach.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, just posting it here to let everyone aware.
it should be used this annotation: `@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(localSecondaryIndexName = "fieldIdLocalIndex")`

```
    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(localSecondaryIndexName = "fieldIdLocalIndex")
    public String getFieldId() {
        return fieldId;
    }
```